JSColor.hide() not working as expected on Android
I'm working on a website for doodling (https://dewdul.com/dewdul-board) and I've integrated JSColor (https://jscolor.com/docs/) library for color picking. My issue is that the default settings available for closing/hiding the color picker are not working as I would expect them to and is acting differently on mobile devices.
I'm using the following presets for the JSColor including the hideOnLeave and hideOnPaletteClick....
let customColors =  [
            '#2C2B2B', '#FFEE92', '#17C3B2', '#71A5DE', '#C27EC2', '#FE6D73',
        ];

    jscolor.presets.default = {
        palette: customColors,
        //paletteCols: 12,
        hideOnLeave: true,
        hideOnPaletteClick: true,
    };

However, just using these defaults is only resulting in the picker closing when I tap once and release on the canvas, rather than going right into the drawing with a click and drag. Again, this is only happening on mobile.
To fix this, I attempted to call JSColor.hide(); within the pointerup event........ This works........... except there is a really weird issue where when I start to draw, it is acting as if the colorpicker is still open and will change the color while I am drawing. (Please feel free to test this out on my website (its kind of hard to describe).
Honestly I would prefer to stick with just using the hideOnLeave, if it actually hides the picker whenever you click and drag, and not just when you click and release... (again... working on PC!!) and I think this is the root of my issue, as I would expect that to be the normal functionality.
Thank you for taking the time to read through my issue!!

Sent an email to dev@jscolor.com and they helped me find a solution :) It's probably a bug - but as a workaround I can use the following on a pointerdown event to fix this issue.


if (!event.hasOwnProperty('_data_jscolor')) {
    jscolor.hide();
}



